# How does "Binding" knows which object I want (Xaml, DataGridTextColumn)

Tags: xaml, object, datagrid

Sorry for the unclear question: I didn't know how to write what I wanted to ask, but my code helps me to clear it:

VehicleWidget.xaml

```
<local:ParkingWidget x:Class="VehiclesWidget"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Widgets" Loaded="ParkingWidget_Loaded" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="65" Width="420">
<Grid Height="61" Width="411">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>    <!--0-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> <!--1-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> <!--2-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="298"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="38*" />
        <!--3-->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>   <!--0-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!--1-->
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>    <!--2-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!--3-->
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>   <!--4-->           
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label
        Content="Vehicles"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <Button
        Name="btnRefresh"
        Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
        Content="Refresh"
        Width="98"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Click="btnRefresh_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,2,257,2">
    </Button>

    <DataGrid
        Name="VehiclesDataGrid"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="0,0,3,0">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" x:Name="timeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Time}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="TicketId" x:Name="tickedIdColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=TicketId}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LPN" x:Name="lpnColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=LPN}" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Picture" x:Name="pictureColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=TicketId}" Visibility="Hidden">
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="Hyperlink_Click"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class" x:Name="classColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=HeightClassification}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" x:Name="weightColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Weight}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Orientation" x:Name="orientationColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Orientation.Degrees}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Piston1" x:Name="piston1Column" Binding="{Binding Path=Piston1}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Piston2" x:Name="piston2Column" Binding="{Binding Path=Piston2}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" x:Name="locationColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Location}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

In "VehicleWidget.xaml.cs" I have "List vehicles", and in "Vehicle" class I have properties of: Piston1, Piston2, size, LPN and of course Weight

The follows line, add column to the grid and names it "Weight" and bind to it Weight.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" x:Name="weightColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Weight}" />
```

How does the binding knows to choose which object, takes it's properties?

I ask this question because I want to bind a property of different object (not Vehicle, like in this example, but NewVehicle, which inherited from Vehicle).

Comment: It's explained in full detail in the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings in XAML are a "link" between a variable or object and a xaml widget like textview, gridviews etc. There are a lot of ways to use it. I will give you a few examples:

-1- A property from your sourcecode is binded to a textblock. When the variable changes its value, the textblock becomes updated:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

-2- More complicated example, the textbox's value becomes updated if the variable changes and the variable becomes updated when the value of the textbox is changed:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeVar, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

-3- Databinding with a converter, means you can write an converter in c# that processes any binded value and returns any custom value/object:

XAML

```
 <TextBlock Text="TrafficLight" Background="{Binding TrafficLightState, Converter={StaticRessource TrafficLightStateToColorConverter}}">
```

C#

```
 public class TrafficLightStateToColorConverter : IValueConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if(value.Equals("Green")) 
           return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Green)
        else if(value.Equals("Yellow")) 
           return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Yellow)
        else
           return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Red)
    }
 }
```

Does that answer your questions, how xaml knows which object has to be used?

Comment: No, I'm not sure about it: what is "TrafficLightState" in the 3rd example? What is the meaning of Converter?

Comment: "A variable from your sourcecode is binded to a textblock" as shown in your example is unclear or even wrong. The binding has to go to a *property* of an *object*. While the property part of the binding is usually clear, there are a few different ways to specify the source object. I'd strongly recommend reading the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: And your example converter does not even return a value from its `Convert` method. Sorry, but this is really a bad answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, i missed the word return. Fixed it. Feel free to improve my answer in your way :)